# Is it a submartingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, conditional-expectation, martingales

I have a process$$X(t,\omega)=\cases{0,\quad \text{if } t<\tau(\omega) \\  1\quad \text{if } t\ge\tau(\omega)}$$

where $\tau$ is a stopping time. I need to show that $X(t, \omega)$ is a submartingale. Can anyone help, especally with the 3 condition i.e for $s\le t$ we have

$$X(s)\le E(X(t)| F(s)) $$ where $F(s)$ is a filtration generated by process $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $X(t)\geq X(s)$. Once you show that $X(t)$ is adapted (which is a good exercise in stopping times), this gives you that $X(s)$ is $F(s)$-measurable and hence,

$$
E(X(t)|F(s))\geq E(X(s)|F(s))=X(s)
$$
almost surely.

Comment: $X(t)$ must be adapted to filtration $F(t)$ because it is a filtration generated by this process. Am I right?

Comment: Well, the way you wrote the question, I guess. But you could also just start with some filtration $F_s$ and be given a stopping time $\tau$. Then, the corresponding $X$ will be $F_s$-adapted.